# Installing dbt using pip on a drive that is not C:

Tags: python, dbt

I am trying to install dbt package using pip. I am unable to complete the installation and I am getting this error;

```
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'd:\cx\new c\dbt-env\scripts\python.exe' 'd:\cx\new c\dbt-env\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Tosh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5ns7y0k2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel cython 'pyarrow>=0.17.0,<0.18.0'
           cwd: None
```

I think th issue is that I have installed python on the D drive and not SSD which is the C drive. If I am correct and this is the issue, I would like to maintain this install in drive D. How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create virtual evironment and install dbt in it.

```
python -m venv venv

# windows
./venv/scripts/activate

# Linux
source /venv/bin/activate 

pip install dbt
```